# How can I put a module in a modal and pass parameters

Tags: joomla-3.x, custom-module

I'm trying to make all my custom php pages into modules so they fit in the proper windows and are responsive.  So I do not want to use Iframes (as I've done previously).

So I have a module that will read from a database and present the results on a page.   I need to pass this page a parameter (value used in the SQL statement).

I know that I can create Joomla modals using:

```
JHTML::_('behavior.modal');
```

If it was a static page, I could simply link to it with something like this:

```
<a href="http://www.example.com/somepage.html" 
class="modal" rel="{size: {x: 700, y: 500}, handler:'iframe'}" 
id="modalLink1">
Click here to see this interesting page</a>
```

But I need to know how to do that to have the modal have a Joomla Custom Module in it.   I can create an article with the module embedded in it with Modules Anywhere (that is how I've done the Module itself).

What I'm trying to do is have a form.  When you select a user from a drop down list, you would get an icon that you could click on that would popup the module with all the user info (which is a separate module).

If I wanted to simplify this, I could simply create a div and use a jQuery load to fill the div.   However, I want this as a modal instead because I may have a use for the same thing on other pages.  It will also save real estate on the page if it is a modal instead of a populated div.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The pro version of module anywhere alows you to pass parameters, maybe that will sort your problem.